# How can I build new list from the old one in Python adding two new elements at a time?

Tags: python-3.x, list-comprehension

I work with a tree and my code looks like this

```
new_lst = [x.left for x in lst if x.left] + [x.right for x in lst if x.right]
```

Is there an elegant way to rewrite it with just one list comprehension? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should iterate over the tuple `(x.left, x.right)` inside the list comprehension.

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> Tree = namedtuple('Tree', ['left', 'right'])
>>> L = [Tree(1,2), Tree(0,3), Tree(4,0)]
```

(for the example, `left` and `right` are numbers; they should obviously be subtrees or `None`).

Your version:

```
>>> [x.left for x in L if x.left] + [x.right for x in L if x.right]
[1, 4, 2, 3]
```

In one pass:

```
>>> [t for x in L for t in (x.left, x.right) if t]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Note that the order is different.